# Binding clicker to VM in DataTemplate UWP

Tags: c#, binding, uwp

I have navigation view, where i define CommandBar. In CommandBar, implemented two AppBarButton's:

```
        <NavigationView x:Name="NavView">
            <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="24,10,0,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock
                            Margin="0,0,0,10"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            FontSize="28"
                            Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                            Text="{Binding}" />
                        <CommandBar
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="0,0,10,0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
                            <AppBarButton
                                Icon="Edit"
                                Label="Feedback" />
                            <AppBarButton
                                Icon="OtherUser"
                                Label="ChangeUser" />
                        </CommandBar>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
```

I would like bind that's AppBarButtons with methods in ViewModel, but i can't do that.I try make like that:

```
<AppBarButton
    Icon="Edit"
    Label="Feedback"
    Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.Foo}"/>
```

But it's not work. On compilation appear error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
I'm tried add into `<DataTemplate x:DataType>`, and binding to method like that:

```
<AppBarButton
        Icon="Edit"
        Label="Feedback"
        Click="{x:Bind Foo}"/>
```

It's compiled, but on runtime is throwing exception and disappeared navigation header.
Tell me please, how i can binding this AppBarButtons to my methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you want to use `x:bind` to bind the button in HeaderTemplate, you should find the datacontext and bind the ViewModel.

Try to new a ViewModel and set it to datacontext.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public void Foo()
    {
    }
}


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
```

You need to add dataType inhead.

`DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ViewModel"`

All the code in xaml below.

```
    <NavigationView x:Name="NavView">
        <NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ViewModel">
                <Grid Margin="24,10,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="0,0,0,10"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        FontSize="28"
                        Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"
                        Text="{Binding}" />
                    <CommandBar
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="0,0,10,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        DefaultLabelPosition="Right">
                        <AppBarButton
                            Icon="Edit"
                            Label="Feedback" 
                            Click="{x:Bind Foo}"/>
                        <AppBarButton
                            Icon="OtherUser"
                            Label="ChangeUser" 
                            Click="{x:Bind Foo}"/>
                    </CommandBar>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </NavigationView.HeaderTemplate>
        </NavigationView>
```

Please press F5 to run.

[image]

When you click the Feedback that you can see xaml call the Foo.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working! Tell me please, must we define DataContext everywhere we use ViewModel, or, it actually like for current example?

Comment: @Artem For you want to use x:Bind the good pattern is use DataContext. But you can use binding to bind the element property.